I get an HTTP 405 ERROR when trying to create an order with the stripe API
I'm currently trying to implement the stripe payments API. I just want to be able to create orders. My checkout -> route.ts looks as follows:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Stripe from 'stripe'

export const POST = async(req: NextRequest) => {
  
  const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!);

  if (req.method === "POST") {


    try {

      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [
          {
            // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
            price: 'price_1OxTsSP9KbrT43tOejNZykxO',
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/success',
        cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cancel',
      });
      return NextResponse.json({url: session.url})
    } catch (err:any) {
      return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Error aufgetreten.'}, {status: 500})
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.json({message: "OKAY"})

}

For checkout -> page.tsx that's the relevant code:
"use client"
import { useCartContext } from "@/utils/CartProvider"
import Image from "next/image"
import { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import React from 'react';

import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';


export default function Checkout() {

    const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!);
    
    const createCheckout = async () => {
        const stripe = await stripePromise
        console.log(stripe)

        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/checkout", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify({priceId:"price_1OxTsSP9KbrT43tOejNZykxO"})
        })
        const data = await response.json()
        if(response.ok) {
            window.location.href=data.url
            //stripe?.redirectToCheckout(data.url)
        }
}

And my button has this html:
<form action="/api/checkout" method="POST">
                            <section>
                                <button type="submit" role="link">
                                    Checkout
                                </button>
                            </section>
</form>

Whenever I run the project and click on checkout I get a Response window with the stripe checkout URL wrapped in JSON. Like this: {url: "......"} for the /api/checkout URL.
When I refresh the URL a http 405 error occurs.
I watched countless videos and read articles but can't figure it out.

Where does 405 error exactly occur? Is it at Checkout Session page (Stripe hosted payment page)? Or your the API response from your server? Can you you share the screenshot or video?
